# Coffee machine simulator - removing an empty line

Tags: python

i finished this coffee machine simulator but i have a small problem.
How can i remove the line added by the check function after i enter the 'e' or 'l' or 'c'?
Below is the code and a sample of the undesired output and the desired input.

The code:

```
import os
import time
menu = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee_l": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}

resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
    "money":0
}

def money():
    quarter=0.25
    dime=0.1
    nickel=0.05
    pennie=0.01
    qu=float(input("Inset quarters: "))
    di=float(input("Insert dimes: "))
    ni=float(input("Insert nickels: "))
    pen=float(input("Insert pennies: "))
    total_paid=qu*quarter+di*dime+ni*nickel+pen*pennie
    return total_paid

def check(drink):
    if drink == 'espresso':
        if resources['water'] >= 50 and resources['coffee'] >= 18:
            return ''
        elif resources['water'] <= 50:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough water."
        elif resources['coffee'] <= 18:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough coffee."
    elif drink=='latte':
        if resources['water'] >= 200 and resources['milk'] >= 150 and resources['coffee'] >= 24:
            return ""
        elif resources['water'] < 50:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough water."
        elif resources['coffee'] < 18:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough coffee."
        elif resources['milk'] < 150:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough milk."
            
    elif drink=='cappuccino':
        if resources['water'] >= 250 and resources['milk'] >= 100 and resources['coffee'] >= 24:
            return ""
        elif resources['water'] < 250:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough water."
        elif resources['coffee'] < 24:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough coffee."
        elif resources['milk'] < 100:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough milk."



def make_drink(drink):
    if drink == "espresso":
        resources['water']  -= 50
        resources['coffee'] -= 18
        resources['money'] += 1.5
    elif drink == "latte":
        resources['water']  -= 50
        resources['coffee'] -= 18
        resources['milk']   -= 150
        resources['money'] += 2.5
    elif drink == "cappuccino":
        resources['water']  -= 250
        resources['coffee'] -= 18
        resources['milk']   -= 100
        resources['money'] += 3
    else:
        print("Not sure what drink was made")
    return

def replenish():
    resources['water']  += 300
    resources['milk']   += 200
    resources['coffee'] += 100
    return

while True:
    print("Welcome to the coffee machine.")
    m="Espresso = 1.5$\nLatte = 2.5$\nCappuccino = 3.0$\n"
    print(m)
    choice=input("​What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino)(e/l/c): ")
    if choice=='report':
        print(f"Water: {resources['water']}ml\nMilk: {resources['milk']}ml\nCoffee: {resources['coffee']}ml\nMoney: {round(resources['money'],2)}$")
    elif choice=='replenish':
        replenish()
    elif choice=='e':
        chk=check('espresso')
        print(chk)
        if chk=='':
            mo=money()
            if mo == menu['espresso']['cost']:
                make_drink('espresso')
                print('Here is your coffee')
            elif mo > menu['espresso']['cost']:
                make_drink('espresso')
                print(f'Here is your coffee, and here is your change {round(mo-menu["espresso"]["cost"], 2)} $')
            elif mo < menu['espresso']['cost']:
                print(f'​Sorry that\'s not enough money. Money refunded.')
    elif choice=='l':
        chk=check('latte')
        print(chk)
        if chk=='':
            mo=money()
            if mo == menu['latte']['cost']:
                print('Here is your coffee')
            elif mo > menu['latte']['cost']:
                print(f'Here is your coffee, and here is your change {mo-menu["latte"]["cost"]} $')
                resources['money']=mo+resources['money']
            elif mo < menu['latte']['cost']:
                print(f'​Sorry that\'s not enough money. Money refunded.')
    elif choice=='c':
        chk=check('cappuccino')
        print(chk)
        if chk=='':
            mo=money()
            if mo == menu['cappuccino']['cost']:
                print('Here is your coffee')
            elif mo > menu['cappuccino']['cost']:
                print(f'Here is your coffee, and here is your change {mo-menu["cappuccino"]["cost"]} $')
                resources['money']=mo+resources['money']
            elif mo < menu['cappuccino']['cost']:
                print(f'​Sorry that\'s not enough money. Money refunded.')
        
    elif choice=='off':
        break
    time.sleep(3)   
    os.system('clear')
```

The undesired output:

```
Welcome to the coffee machine.
Espresso = 1.5$
Latte = 2.5$
Cappuccino = 3.0$

What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino)(e/l/c): e

Inset quarters:
```

The desired output:

```
Welcome to the coffee machine.
Espresso = 1.5$
Latte = 2.5$
Cappuccino = 3.0$

What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino)(e/l/c): e
Inset quarters:
```

How can I do that without ruining the code?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without a newline or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the line

```
print(chk)
```

to

```
if chk:
    print(chk)
```

The empty line comes from calling check("expresso") and returning an empty line (no failure message to display)

So you only print `chk` if it has a message, but you don't print it if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

when `check('espresso')` exceuted, `chk` value became empty string. To solve it, you should validate if `chk` value is not an empty string and then print, else don't do anything. You can change the line :

```
print(chk)
```

with this:

```
print(chk) if chk else ''
```